# Nativescript TabView Nested child route

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I want to have child views with in the `TabView` tag

Here is my code for the `TabView`

```
 <StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'Home'}" >
   <Label text="This is Label in Tab 1"></Label>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet> 
 </StackLayout>
 <StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'History'}">
   <Label text="This is Label in Tab 2"></Label>
 </StackLayout>
 <StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'Feedback'}">
   <Label text="This is Label in Tab 3"></Label>
 </StackLayout>
</TabView>
```

As you can see I have the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` tag in the first view which is where I want to load a child view.

Here is the code for the routes

```
export const routes = [
    { path: '', component: tabviewCompoenent, children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'childComponenet', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'childComponenet', component: childComponenet}
     ]
    }
];
```

Doing the above gives the following in the console

> Successfully synced application org.nativescript.AngularStarter on
>   device 169.254.138.177:5555.
>       JS: Angular 2 is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
>       JS: Selected tab index: 0
>       JS: EXCEPTION: Error in pages/other/other.component.html:19:13 caused by: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous
>   value: 'false'. Current value: 'true'.
>       JS: ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'false'. Current value: 'true'.
>       JS: ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
>       JS: Error: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'false'. Current value: 'true'.
>       JS:     at ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError.Error (native)
>       JS:     at ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError.BaseError [as constructor]
>   (/data/data/org.nativescript.AngularStarter/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:1104:38)
>       JS:     at new ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError (/data/data/org.nativescript.AngularStarter/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:5092:20)
>       JS:     at checkBinding (/data/data/org.nativescript.AngularStarter/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:5236:23)
>       JS:     at Wrapper_NgIf.check_ngIf (/CommonModule/NgIf/wrapper.ngfactory.js:12:23)
>       JS:     at DebugAppView._View_tabviewCompoenent0.detectChangesInternal
>   (/AppModule/tabviewCompoenent/component.ngfactory.js:202:19)
>       JS:     at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChanges (/data/data/org.nativescript.AngularStarter/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9305:18)
>       JS:     at DebugAppView.detectChanges (/data/data/org.nativescript.AngularStarter/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9410:48)
>       JS:     at DebugAppView.AppView.detectViewChildrenChanges (/data/data/org.nativescript.AngularStarter/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9331:23)
>       JS:     at DebugAppView._View_tabviewCompoenent_Host0.detectChangesInternal
>   (/AppModule/tabviewCompoenent/host.ngfactory.js:33:8)
>       JS: ERROR CONTEXT:
>       JS: [object Object]
>       JS: Error: Error in pages/other/other.component.html:19:13 caused by: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value:
>   'false'. Current value: 'true'.

Comment: Having the same issue with nested router-outlets. Could you fix this issue?

Comment: Anyone figured this out yet?